# CSS Google Chrome border-top

Tags: css

I have a menu:

- Menu1 (id menu-item-290)
- Menu2  191
- Menu3  192
- Menu4  193
- Menu5  194

when I hover the menu there is coming a border-top and when I click on it there is coming only in Firefox a border-top on focus and not in Chrome

is there any problem with the code ?

```
.menu-item-290:focus
{
    border-top: 3px solid white;
    -webkit-border-before: 3px solid white;
}

.menu-item-290:hover
{
    border-top:3px solid white;
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Do you want the border or do you not want the border?

Comment: You stated `Menu1 (id menu-item-290)` but in your css you are targeting `.menu-item-290` which is a class. I assume it's a class in your html since it works in some browsers

Comment: Huangism

I changed all classes to # but still doens't work.

www.markbodde.nl/jamfabriek

this is the site please test on firefox and chrome.

Comment: if I add a hover it words great but when I change the "Hover" to "Focus" it doens't work